# facebook ads not install tracking

Tags: facebook

I have this really odd problem. The bosses in the office decided to do facebook tracking by using the [FBSettings publishInstall:<appIDhere>] in the app delegate. This works because the graph.facebook.com/<appID>/activities, etc are called, and Facebook returned true.

However, the problem is that this is NOT showing up in the dashboard. The app_activate shows up just fine, it's just that the app install is not showing at all.

So, my questions are:

1. Why is it that the install is not read correctly? The call is made and facebook response. Why is it that it's not showing up in the dashboard?
2. Does facebook do any other filtering? For example, if I delete the app and then reinstall, should the app be counted to have installed twice? In this case, the call to graph.facebook.com/ is made twice to send the MOBILE_APP_INSTALL activity. After this, does facebook do any other filtering? e.g. they remember device tokens, etc?
3. I am not quite sure how facebook differentiate using the URL scheme. I presume that this is to differentiate people who upgraded compared to people who installed. How does the fb<appid> help as a URL Scheme?

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: So no installs are appearing in the app insights? silly question, but you haven't disabled the ability for the SDKs events to register as installs, have you? (there's an option for this in the Advanced tab of app settings)

Comment: No. They are both enabled (the toggle said "YES")

Comment: Then the first time an event is received from a given user it should register as an install in insights and in the app dashboard - the url scheme helps the Facebook for iPhone app know that your app is or isn't already installed, but the tracking of a new install is via the activateApp event ('publishInstall' if you're using a version of the SDK which is older that 3.6)

Comment: I understand the part where the first "activate" event will be treated as install. However, the problem is that the install (the call to graph.facebook.com is made, and the event is MOBILE_APP_INSTALL), and facebook does respond. However, it's not showing in the dashboard. <br/> Do you also know how facebook figure out whether the app is or isn't already installed using the URL scheme? How do they use the scheme to check, exactly?

Comment: The URL scheme is used from inside Facebook's native app so it can detect if the app is already installed and so it can context switch to that app, it's not directly related to how tracking of a new install happens, which as far as i know is entirely based on the activateApp event